# extracting digits from string in c#

Tags: c#

I'm writing a json deserializer for a phone object.

One of the properties is the phone number. In my database, I store the number as a string of digits.

I have the string called `IncomingClientJsonPhoneCandidate` and I'm writing a loop that goes through each character of the string and adds the value to a string builder if the character passes a byte.TryParse.

I'm wondering if there's a better way to do this.
Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: If you want to check if a character is a digit use `char.IsDigit` it should be faster than `byte.TryParse`

Comment: @digEmAll this of course will accept characters that many might be unable to read.  There are 310 digit characters; here's as many of them as I could get to come across without much trouble: `0123456789٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹߀߁߂߃߄߅߆߇߈߉०१२३४५६७८९০১২৩৪৫৬৭৮৯੦੧੨੩੪੫੬੭੮੯૦૧૨૩૪૫૬૭૮૯୦୧୨୩୪୫୬୭୮୯௦௧௨௩௪௫௬௭௮௯౦౧౨౩౪౫౬౭౮౯೦೧೨೩೪೫೬೭೮೯൦൧൨൩൪൫൬൭൮൯๐๑๒๓๔๕๖๗๘๙໐໑໒໓໔໕໖໗໘໙༠༡༢༣༤༥༦༧༨༩០១២៣៤៥៦៧៨៩᠐᠑᠒᠓᠔᠕᠖᠗᠘᠙᧐᧑᧒᧓᧔᧕᧖᧗᧘᧙᱐᱑᱒᱓᱔᱕᱖᱗᱘᱙꘠꘡꘢꘣꘤꘥꘦꘧꘨꘩０１２３４５６７８９`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try

```
string ExtractNumericCharacters(string s)
{
    return string.IsNullOrEmpty(s) ? s : new string(s.Where(c => char.IsDigit(c)).ToArray());
}
```

You can also use a method group conversion rather than a lambda:

```
string ExtractNumericCharacters(string s)
{
    return string.IsNullOrEmpty(s) ? s : new string(s.Where(char.IsDigit).ToArray());
}
```

**EDIT**

To see why you can't use `ToString()` here, let's pull apart the complex expression:

```
string ExtractNumericCharacters(string s)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
        return s;

    IEnumerable<char> numericChars = s.Where(char.IsDigit);

    // numericChars is a Linq iterator; if you call ToString() on this object, you'll get the type name.
    // there's no string constructor or StringBuilder Append overload that takes an IEnumerable<char>
    // so we need to get a char[].  The ToArray() method iterates over the WhereEnumerator, copying
    // the sequence into a new array; this is functionally equivalent to using a foreach loop with an if statement.

    char[] numericCharArray = numericChars.ToArray();

    // now we can make a string!

    return new string(numericCharArray);
}
```

If you want to stick with your original approach of using a StringBuilder, you could pass the `char[]` to the StringBuilder's Append method instead of calling `new string(...`.

**EDIT 2**

In addition to adding some detail above about loops, thanks to McKay's comments, it occurred to me that I could add the query comprehension syntax.  It's a good example of why I generally prefer the extension method syntax; in this case, the extension method is much more concise:

```
string ExtractNumericCharacters(string s)
{
    return string.IsNullOrEmpty(s) ? s : new string((from c in s where char.IsDigit(c) select c).ToArray());
}
```

Comment: Ah, this is much better. Can I do a ToString instead of ToArray?

Comment: You can of course call `ToString()`, but you won't get a meaningful result.  Instead, you'll get `"System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereEnumerableIterator\`1[System.Char]"`

Comment: Is the `ToArray()` necessary?

Comment: ok, cool, I got it, thanks for your suggestion; much better than my loop idea!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan yes; there's string constructor that takes a `char[]` argument, but none that takes `IEnumerable<char>`.

Comment: @phhog thanks, I thought that there might be an `IEnumerable<char>` one - would certainly make sense nowadays with the prevalence of Linq.

Comment: I agree absolutely -- in fact, I thought one had been added, but I checked just to be sure.  There must have been some other method that I saw recently that had an `IEnumerable<something>` overload added.

Comment: I'm doing ThePhoneNumber = IncomingClientJsonPhoneCandidate.Where(c => char.IsDigit(c)).ToString(); Is this good?

Comment: @frenchie No, see my previous comment ("you can of course call...").  See also the edited answer for more detail.

Comment: Note that this is actually a loop specifically being executed during the ToArray() call.

Comment: @McKay absolutely.  Linq gives a more concise expression, but it does not change the basic fact that we need to check each character to see if it's a digit.  That will require a loop, even if we don't ourselves code the loop explicitly.

Comment: @phoog Yes, I think this is a good solution (and I gave it a +1), but it is still a loop it just doesn't look like one. But he seems to think that loops are a bad way of doing things, and Linq might or might not be what he wants.

Comment: @McKay Any programmer who thinks loops are a bad way of doing things ought to think about a new career!  I will edit the answer so that it's more explicit about the "behind the scenes" loop; thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I would note that it's not obvious (by superficial examination) that this Linq statement will blow up with a null argument...really there should be a null check (or an assertion) to validate the argument before scanning, e.g.:

string ExtractNumericCharacters(string s)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(s)) 
                return s;
            
            return new string(s.Where(char.IsDigit).ToArray());
        }

Comment: @phoog oh even better with the null coalesce operator I'll steal that!

Comment: @karfus that's the conditional operator, not the null coalescing operator.  The null coalescing operator replaces a null value with something else, but in this case we want to keep the original value if it is null, and replace it if it is non null.

Answer (score 0):

```
char.IsDigit()
```

(that's all you really need, but I have to put more in here for character limit)

Comment: That's if I keep the loop. I'm looking to get rid of the loop and a one-liner function call that extracts digits from a string, using regular expression.

Comment: you could do that if you want, but a regex that does the same thing without a loop, will be harder to code, and will be less performant.

Comment: And I don't think you can even do it in regex without a loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static string GetNumberFromStrFaster(string str)
    {
      str = str.Trim();
      Match m = new Regex(@"^[\+\-]?\d*\.?[Ee]?[\+\-]?\d*$",         
      RegexOptions.Compiled).Match(str);
      return (m.Value);
    }
```

using regular expression

Comment: What is this all about? Where do floating point numbers come into this question about telephone numbers? And isn't `Regex` a bit of a sledgehammer?

Comment: Even if a regex was the right tool, it's awfully silly to compile the regex when you're only going to use it once. Use the static methods on `Regex` instead.

Comment: Ok, that looks close to what I want. I'm not familiar with regex: does this regex only extract digits or also does some formatting? I'm only looking to extracts the digits, the formatting is handled in the serialization, with a long loop (for now). Also, is this thread safe?

Comment: yep it should give you the numbers as well as float point numbers but if you want just digit use something like  "^\d+$" it should not do any formatting just extracting digits from number.

Comment: Even if this worked (it only grabs the first group?), it should still need a loop to get all of them, and it would probably be less performant. Regex is the wrong way to go.

Comment: It does not require any loop what so ever if you pass string you will get all the numbers in the string!!! not sure where the loop came from ant the question asked to avoid loop.

Answer (score 0):

Int32.TryParse("13231321") will save you the need for a loop

Comment: That'll just tell me if the string only contains number; what if I want to extract the numbers from a string that contains all sort of characters?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use an existing deserializer either .NET's or [Json.net](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx)?

Comment: Because there's some if/then logic that I implement during the deserialization. I'm using .net's javascriptserializer with a custom javascriptconverter.